# How do I read the text within in a <pre> in python?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to make a script that detects whether or not an Instagram username is taken. I found that using the url
[https://www.instagram.com/{username}/?__a=1](https://www.instagram.com/%7Busername%7D/?__a=1) will fill with info about the account if the name exists, but if the name doesn't exist, the page will just have {} inside of a pre and nothing else.

I'm using Requests and BeautifulSoup to scrape the page. Here is a script I wrote to test this out:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

username = input("Enter the username you would like to check:")
account_url=('https://www.instagram.com/' + username + '/?__a=1')
r = requests.get(account_url)

print(r.text)
```

The displaying the text works, but even when I put a username that doesn't exist or a random jumble of letters, it always returns a bunch of html that I don't see in inspect element on the actual url. How do I make it just returns the text inside of the pre? I just want to detect if the site shows nothing so I can determine whether or not it's a taken username.

Also, when you load the instagram ?__a=1 url with a non-existing username, inspect element will say there was an error 404, but testing the status of the requests variable in python always comes back with 200, which is success. I'm pretty inexperienced with python because I haven't used it in a very long time so some help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When I put non-existing username, `{}` is returned. Is this correct behaviour?

Comment: @Ohucal Is your problem solved ?

Comment: @AndrejKesely Yes thats whats supposed to happen. For some reason on my computer requests is working differently and not doing that and im not sure why.

Comment: @RobinFrcd not really, ive figured out that it either has something to do with my software or internet because it works for other people, but not for me. One time I had a vpn on and when i turned it off, it started working, but then stopped again after a while. I have no clue what that has to do with requests but apparently my internet affects it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a list of accounts which are not taken you could use this

```
import requests
not_taken = []
user_names = ["randomuser1", "randomuser2", "randomuser3", "etc..."]

for name in user_names:
    response = requests.get(f"https://www.instagram.com/{name}/?__a=1")
    if response.status_code == 404:
        not_taken.append(name)
```

Now you can use not_taken as you want , for example :

```
print(not_taken)
```